# Admin add product to order observer Event name

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

What i am trying I want After Add product to Order from admin i want to trigger my action . I tried with below event but its not working for me can you please let me what event i have to use

- `sales_order_place_before`
- `adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data`
- `sales_order_save_after`

config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <NameSpace_AdditionalProduct>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </NameSpace_AdditionalProduct>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <additionalproduct>
                <class>NameSpace_AdditionalProduct_Helper</class>
            </additionalproduct>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <additionalproduct>
                <class>NameSpace__AdditionalProduct_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>additionalproduct_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </additionalproduct>
        </models>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <custom_promopack_order_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>additionalproduct/observer</class>
                        <method>addPromoPack</method>
                    </custom_promopack_order_observer>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

observer.php

```
public function addPromoPack(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    Mage::log("================================hello========================");
    die('heeeeeeeeeeeeeeel');
}
```

Comment: use Mage::log('test') instead of echo and die.

Comment: @sohel : tried still not working

Comment: Share how you register model in global scope.

Comment: @sohel: i updated  my config on question section

Comment: Your observer function name should be `addPromoPack` instead of `productlevelChanges`

Comment: Double underscores in class name isn't correct too.

Comment: i corrected those underscore issue Still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try these:

- `sales_quote_item_set_product`
- `sales_quote_add_item`
- `sales_quote_product_add_after`

Comment: this event worked sales_quote_item_set_product

Answer (score 0):

Please try following event

```
sales_model_service_quote_submit_after
```